# file copy to remote server access error

Tags: c#, iis

I kept getting Access error on the following code:

```
var fileName = "test.dgi";
var local = Path.Combine(@"C:\aaa", fileName);            
var remote = Path.Combine(@"\\sw933chipqw001\tmp\", fileName);
```

Error I got is:

> Access to the path '\sw933chipqw001\tmp\test.dgi' is denied.

I tried to give Read/Write access to **IUSR, IIS_ISURS** and the service account I set in the app pool. nothing worked. I'm using IIS7.

But if I add "**Everyone**" with the Read/Write access, it works. Anyone know what is the specific account that I need to give permission to?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Just some tips for future: 1. That code wouldn't throw that error - post the actual line that causes the exception. 2. Never use 'doesn't work' - always explain why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well the default account that an app pool is running in IIS7 is:

```
IIS AppPool\<AppPoolName>
```

In your case it's probably

```
IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool
```

[Here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) is a little bit more info.

Comment: It doesn't work... I added the "Identity" specified in the Process Model of the App Pool in IIS, but that doesn't work. Any more ideas? Is there any special port I need to open for File.Copy?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to grant "Authenticated Users" full control on the remote folder and it works!